# Open AppStore if app is not installed on iOS

Tags: ios, app-store

I would like to open Appstore if app is not installed on iPhone. E.g. I want to open facebook from my app. I'm doing it like that

```
UIApplication *ourApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSString *ourPath = @"fb://profile/1234";
NSURL *ourURL = [NSURL URLWithString:ourPath];
[ourApplication openURL:ourURL];
```

But if facebook app is not installed on device I get such error:

```
LaunchServices: ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme fb
```

in such case I would like to take user to facebook app on AppStore. I know I can do it like that:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=294409923&mt=8";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

but how I will know what is Facebook AppStore id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the return value of `openURL:`. If it returns `NO`, then create a `SKStoreProductViewController` setup for the desired app.

```
if (![ourApplication openURL:ourURL]) {
    // can't launch app for 'fb' scheme
    // Create and display SKStoreProductViewController
}
```

If you don't want to use `SKStoreProductViewController` then use the `openURL` code you have at the end of your question instead.